# How do you add 2 subclassof's in an OWL class?

Tags: rdf, owl

[image]

I'm trying to make a class statement for Canon Camera. But I don't know if 2 subclassOf statements are allowed in the Canon Camera class which points to both "Camera" and "Canon Product".

This is what I have so far:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID=”product”>
    <rdfs:comment>Products form a class. </rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:ID=”Camera”>
    <rdfs:comment>Photography device</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Device</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource=”#product”/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:ID=”Canon Product”>
    <rdfs:comment>A canon device</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Device</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource=”#product”/>
</owl:Class>
```

I need to know if this is possible and correct:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Canon Camera">
    <rdfs:comment>A canon camera</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Canon Product"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Camera"/>
</owl:Class>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that spaces are not legal characters in IRIs (so `#Canon Product` and `Canon Camera` are not syntactically legal identifiers), your example is fine. You've expressed an ontology in which every instance of `Canon Camera` is inferred to be an instance of both `Canon Product` and `Camera`.

Note, however, that what you have *not* captured is the reverse inference: your model does not express that everything that is both a "Camera" and a "Canon Product" is always a "Canon Camera".

If you want to capture this inverse relationship as well, you need to work with an OWL-specific construct, instead of just adding `rdfs:subClassOf` relations. One easy way to express it is using  `owl:intersectionOf`, like this:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="CanonCamera">
    <rdfs:comment>A canon camera</rdfs:comment>
    <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#CanonProduct"/>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Camera"/>
    </owl:intersectionOf>
</owl:Class>
```

or using Turtle syntax (which is easier to read than RDF/XML):

```
  :CanonCamera a owl:Class ;
      owl:intersectionOf ( :CanonProduct :Camera ) .
```

This says that the class extension of `:CanonCamera` is *exactly equal* to the intersection of the class extensions of `:CanonProduct` and `:Camera`. In other words:

1. all things which are *both* a `:CanonProduct` and a `:Camera` are inferred to be a `:CanonCamera`
2. all things which are a `:CanonCamera` are inferred to be both a `:CanonProduct` and a `:Camera`